# Scrapy CookieEnabled doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap a website and I've got `COOKIE_ENABLED` set to true, however sometimes I get the following response from the request:

[image]

Where the corresponding response html is:

```html
<html>
    <head><base href="http://www.yad2.co.il/Nadlan/sales_info.php?NadlanID=4b3746939d3ab7d5be7c38efab70f0b59e0">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="28FEB2002" />
        <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function addFields(formObj) {  } function redirect(commitType) { var cookieenabled = false; if (navigator.cookieEnabled) { if (navigator.cookieEnabled==true) { var exdate=new Date(); exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+1); document.cookie="PRID=" +escape(genPid())+";path=/; expires="+exdate.toGMTString()+"; domain=.yad2.co.il"; cookieenabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("PRID")!=-1)? true : false; } } if (cookieenabled) { if (commitType=="reload") window.location.reload(true); else { var oFrm = document.createElement("form"); var oEnvlp = document.getElementById("frmPlsHldr"); oFrm.method = "post"; addFields(oFrm); oEnvlp.appendChild (oFrm); oFrm.submit(); } } else { var oJSCookieMSGObj = document.getElementById('JSCookieMSG'); oJSCookieMSGObj.style.display = 'block'; } } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:white">
        <div style='display:none' id='sbbhscc'></div><script type="text/javascript">sbbvscc='%3c%73%65%6c%65%63%74%20%69%64%3d"%73%62%62%5f%45%75%68%51%50%49%58%72"%20%73%74%79%6c%65%3d"%64%69%73%70%6c%61%79%3a%6e%6f%6e%65"%3e%3c%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%79%44%51%76%4f%27%3e%73%48%42%3c%2f%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%3e%3c%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%20%20%53%45%4c%45%43%54%45%44%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%4c%6f%79%74%27%3e%79%68%71%6e%4f%4b%3c%2f%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%3e%3c%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%49%43%46%62%71%45%27%3e%63%66%45%67%3c%2f%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%3e%3c%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%57%62%56%69%27%3e%75%58%77%44%4b%3c%2f%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%3e%3c%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%75%4b%76%57%4c%27%3e%47%6b%48%3c%2f%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%3e%3c%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%52%4c%54%4a%27%3e%77%44%55%3c%2f%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%3e%3c%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%5a%44%71%27%3e%4e%78%49%3c%2f%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%3e%3c%2f%73%65%6c%65%63%74%3e%3c%66%6f%72%6d%20%69%64%3d"%73%62%62%5f%6e%4c%73%52%7a"%20%6d%65%74%68%6f%64%3d"%70%6f%73%74"%20%73%74%79%6c%65%3d"%64%69%73%70%6c%61%79%3a%6e%6f%6e%65"%3e%3c%69%6e%70%75%74%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%27%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%27%20%74%79%70%65%3d%27%63%68%65%63%6b%62%6f%78%27%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%4a%42%77%27%2f%3e%3c%69%6e%70%75%74%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%27%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%27%20%74%79%70%65%3d%27%63%68%65%63%6b%62%6f%78%27%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%57%5a%4a%27%2f%3e%3c%69%6e%70%75%74%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%27%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%27%20%74%79%70%65%3d%27%63%68%65%63%6b%62%6f%78%27%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%70%42%72%73%6e%27%2f%3e%3c%69%6e%70%75%74%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%27%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%27%20%74%79%70%65%3d%27%63%68%65%63%6b%62%6f%78%27%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%47%46%70%41%4d%27%2f%3e%3c%69%6e%70%75%74%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%27%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%27%20%74%79%70%65%3d%27%63%68%65%63%6b%62%6f%78%27%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%6b%77%74%79%61%7a%42%27%2f%3e%3c%69%6e%70%75%74%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%27%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%27%20%74%79%70%65%3d%27%63%68%65%63%6b%62%6f%78%27%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%45%67%42%46%27%2f%3e%3c%69%6e%70%75%74%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%27%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%27%20%74%79%70%65%3d%27%63%68%65%63%6b%62%6f%78%27%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%4c%64%72%62%68%4d%27%2f%3e%3c%69%6e%70%75%74%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%27%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%27%20%74%79%70%65%3d%27%63%68%65%63%6b%62%6f%78%27%20%20%43%48%45%43%4b%45%44%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%56%72%57%78%49%27%2f%3e%3c%69%6e%70%75%74%20%6e%61%6d%65%3d%27%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%27%20%74%79%70%65%3d%27%63%68%65%63%6b%62%6f%78%27%20%20%76%61%6c%75%65%3d%27%6c%65%41%76%78%53%27%2f%3e%3c%2f%66%6f%72%6d%3e'; sbbgscc='%66%75%6e%63%74%69%6f%6e%20%73%62%62%5f%46%67%75%28%29%20%7b%20%20%73%62%62%4f%62%6a%20%3d%20%64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e%67%65%74%45%6c%65%6d%65%6e%74%42%79%49%64%28%27%73%62%62%5f%45%75%68%51%50%49%58%72%27%29%3b%20%73%62%62%4f%62%6a%2e%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%73%5b%32%5d%2e%73%65%6c%65%63%74%65%64%20%3d%20%74%72%75%65%3b%20%72%65%74%75%72%6e%20%73%62%62%4f%62%6a%2e%6f%70%74%69%6f%6e%73%5b%73%62%62%4f%62%6a%2e%73%65%6c%65%63%74%65%64%49%6e%64%65%78%5d%2e%74%65%78%74%2e%73%75%62%73%74%72%28%32%2c%31%29%3b%20%7d%66%75%6e%63%74%69%6f%6e%20%73%62%62%5f%73%76%77%65%28%29%20%7b%20%66%75%6e%63%74%69%6f%6e%20%73%62%62%5f%74%69%78%47%6d%41%28%6f%62%6a%41%72%72%29%20%7b%20%76%61%72%20%74%73%3d%27%27%3b%20%66%6f%72%20%28%69%3d%30%3b%20%69%3c%6f%62%6a%41%72%72%2e%6c%65%6e%67%74%68%3b%20%69%2b%2b%29%20%7b%69%66%20%28%6f%62%6a%41%72%72%5b%69%5d%2e%63%68%65%63%6b%65%64%20%3d%3d%20%74%72%75%65%29%20%74%73%20%2b%3d%6f%62%6a%41%72%72%5b%69%5d%2e%76%61%6c%75%65%3b%7d%20%72%65%74%75%72%6e%20%74%73%3b%7d%20%73%62%62%4f%62%6a%20%3d%20%64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e%67%65%74%45%6c%65%6d%65%6e%74%73%42%79%4e%61%6d%65%28%27%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%27%29%3b%20%73%62%62%46%72%6d%3d%64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e%67%65%74%45%6c%65%6d%65%6e%74%42%79%49%64%28%27%73%62%62%5f%6e%4c%73%52%7a%27%29%3b%20%73%62%62%4f%62%6a%5b%31%5d%2e%63%68%65%63%6b%65%64%20%3d%20%74%72%75%65%3b%20%78%3d%73%62%62%5f%74%69%78%47%6d%41%28%73%62%62%46%72%6d%2e%73%62%62%5f%64%42%4b%78%54%59%4f%66%29%3b%20%72%65%74%75%72%6e%20%78%2e%73%75%62%73%74%72%28%35%2c%31%29%3b%20%7d; function genPid() {return %73%62%62%5f%46%67%75%28%29+%73%62%62%5f%73%76%77%65%28%29; }';</script><div id='sbbfrcc' style='position: absolute; top: -10px; left: 30px; font-size:1px'></div>
        <div id='JSCookieMSG' style="display:none"><big><b>Server Notice:</b></big><br/>
Please activate browser cookies to view this site.
<br/><br/>
Incident Id: 585436913aa5b
</div>
        <div id='JSOffMSG'><noscript><big><b>Server Notice:</b></big><br/>
Please activate javascript to view this site.
<br/><br/>
Incident Id: 585436913aa5b
</noscript></div>
        <div id='frmPlsHldr'></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            oJSOffMSG = document.getElementById('JSOffMSG'); oJSOffMSG.style.display = 'none'; try{ y=unescape(sbbvscc.replace(/^<\!\-\-\s*|\s*\-\->$/g,'')); document.getElementById('sbbhscc').innerHTML=y; x=unescape(sbbgscc.replace(/^<\!\-\-\s*|\s*\-\->$/g,'')); } catch(e){ x='function genPid() {return "jser"; }'; } document.write ('<'+'script type="text/javascri'+'pt">'+x+' redirect("reload");</'+'script>'); 
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This seems to happen on and off and I have no idea what's going on.

Has anyone come across something similar?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think this is not actually a cookies problem but a Javascript one. I suspect the cookies the site is trying to read are set using JS and Scrapy does not interprets JS. Just in case, could you try enabling `COOKIES_DEBUG` setting?

Comment: I did. It didn't work. 
In case it's set using JS as you stated, what options do I have to resolve this?